# How to abstract NSXMLParser into separate class -Swift

Tags: ios, swift, nsxmlparser

Using `NSXMLParser` is straight forward, but all the examples I've found place the parsing code inside the `ViewController`and update the UI directly.  I'd like to abstract the parsing into a separate model class and call a function from that class to get its results in my VC.  I can't figure out how to pass my `newForecastsArray` that is updated with the `Parser` results? Right now I'm just passing an empty `array`:

```
class WeatherForecast: NSObject, NSXMLParserDelegate {

    var parser = NSXMLParser()
    var elements = NSMutableDictionary()
    var element = NSString()
    var textForecasts = [String]()
    var location = NSMutableString()
    var layoutKeys = [String]()
    var layoutKey = NSMutableString()
    var conditionsIcons = [String]()
     var newForecastArray = NSMutableArray()


    func getForecasts(lat: String, lon: String,  completionHandler: (result: NSMutableArray) -> Void)  {

        let baseURL = "http://forecast.weather.gov/MapClick.php?lat="
        let suffixURL = "&unit=0&lg=english&FcstType=dwml"

        let url = baseURL + lat + "&lon=" + lon + suffixURL

        newForecastArray = []
        parser = NSXMLParser(contentsOfURL:(NSURL(string: url))!)!
        parser.delegate = self
        parser.parse()

        completionHandler(result: newForecastArray)  //I NEED TO PASS the updated newForecastArray here
    }

    //XMLParser Methods
```

so in my VC I'm trying to call:

```
weatherForecast.getForecasts(lat, lon: lon) { (result) -> Void in
            print(result) 
        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should create a `var` so you can store the `completionHandler` instead of calling it during `getForecasts`. Then, when the XML parsing is complete you can call the `completionHandler` with the actual result.

Note that if you use the same instance of `WeatherForecast` multiple times you'll have issues with callbacks going missing.

Comment: Can you expand on that a little bit?  I'm not sure I follow... a var inside the getForecasts function or outside?

Comment: No, outside - an instance variable, like your `parser` for example

Comment: That's what I was trying to do with newForecastArray, i.e. bind the result to it but how do I pass that value? When I call it now it just passes the empty array

Comment: Because you need to store the callback, not a placeholder array. Without storing the callback you have nothing to call later.

Comment: I implemented a callBack per your answer, but still can't receive my callBack and I think it has to do with multiple instances of WeatherForecast as you suggested...can I get around this problem?

Comment: Every time you call `getForecasts` it should be on a new instance of `WeatherForecast` - and you need to retain the instance until the callback is received.

Comment: But how would I make sure I'm retaining the instance, using GCD or something like that?

Comment: Generally use an instance variable